# Graph Report API data latency and accuracy

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

We are currently using Graph Report API to check the people usage for O365. one of the Report API we were using is getOffice365ActiveUserDetail API (https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(period='D180')). From the output csv file, we found out the user's usage information can somehow be delayed for many days. As I run the report on 2018/03/01, The "Report Refresh date" pointed to 2018/02/24 which is about a week ago.
Another interesting thing was when I use https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActiveUserDetail(date=2018-02-25), I got a few users with "Report Refresh Date" indicated "2018-02-25". does `period='D180'` not include `date=2018-02-25` data if I call report API on 2018/03/01?

From the [Activity Reports in the Office 365 admin center](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Activity-Reports-in-the-Office-365-admin-center-0d6dfb17-8582-4172-a9a9-aed798150263)

> it showed Reports are available for the last 7 days, 30 days, 90 days,
>   and 180 days. Data won't exist for all reporting periods right away.
>   The reports become available within 48 hours.

Does it mean the data should be available in the report within 48 hours? If not, how often the data will be available?

At same time, we are confused about the data accuracy inside the report. for example, we found out someone's YammerLicenseAssignDate is null but HasYammer is "1" and YammerLastActivityDate is 2018-02-24. I am not sure if that's valid combination because how come a user has Yammer license, but not have a YammerLicenseAssignDate?

I am just wondering anyone know when the data will be shown in the report and how accurate the data is. Where can we find out the exact means of each column in the report? [reportRoot: getOffice365ActiveUserDetail](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/reportroot_getoffice365activeuserdetail) doesn't mention the detail meaning of each column.

Comment: have you already figured out how to fix this? currently, I got the same issue here.

and I want to ask you, what is the difference between period=(D7),period=(D30), and period=(D180) ? this report is returned the same things.  @Verona

Comment: the D(x) indicates the how many days period. For example, D7 means the last 7 days report. the API endpoint returns csv file based on last 7 days period. For the issue I mentioned in my case, we ended up to open up a support ticket with MS support. There was a backup queue to queue the report data for those csv. those queue got problems which caused the data didn't refresh. I suggest you open a support ticket with MS support. Good luck

Comment: hi verona, I already try to download using MS Graph API, but the returns in period D7 and D30 is the same values, I didn't see any difference

Comment: check out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/reportroot-getoffice365activeuserdetail?view=graph-rest-1.0 for the detail. it says "Specifies the length of time over which the report is aggregated. The supported values for {period_value} are: D7, D30, D90, and D180. These values follow the format Dn where n represents the number of days over which the report is aggregated." If that is not right, contact to MS support.